# Summing values in a column according to results of calculation

Tags: date, sum, subtraction, sumifs

I want to sum values in a column according to results of calculation.

For example, dates are placed in column `A`. First, I want to subtract values in the column `A` from a static date. Then, according to results (like less than 31, between 31 and 91, greater than 91), I want to sum up values in another column.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include information about the programming language you're seeking help with, and if you already tried to solve this, a code sample that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `SUMIFS` in your question tags I assume that you talk about Excel. This is a screenshot of my dummy data and results:

[image: sumifs results]

You see dates in the column `A`, values to sum up in the column `B`. The static date is in `B1`.

Formula in `C4` (you should copy it downwards):

```
=$B$1-A4
```

Formula in `E2`:

```
=SUMIFS($B$4:$B$9,$C$4:$C$9,"<31")
```

Formula in `F2`:

```
=SUMIFS($B$4:$B$9,$C$4:$C$9,">=31",$C$4:$C$9,"<=91")
```

Formula in `G2`:

```
=SUMIFS($B$4:$B$9,$C$4:$C$9,">91")
```